# How to make a dummy column determining whether a column cell value is a duplicate?

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

So, my data is travel data.

I want to create a column `df['user_type']` in which it'll determine if the `df['user_id']` occurs more than once. If it does occur more than once, I'll list them as a frequent user.

Here is my code below, but it takes way too long:

```
#Column that determines user type
def determine_user_type(val):
  df_freq = df[df['user_id'].duplicated()]

  user_type = ""
  if(val in df_freq['user_id'].values):
    user_type = "Frequent"
  else:
    user_type = "Single"

return user_type

df['user_type'] = df['user_id'].apply(lambda x: determine_user_type(x))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) and for return all dupes add parameter `keep=False`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user_id':list('aaacbbt')})

df['user_type'] = np.where(df['user_id'].duplicated(keep=False), 'Frequent','Single')
```

Alternative:

```
d = {True:'Frequent',False:'Single'}
df['user_type'] = df['user_id'].duplicated(keep=False).map(d)

print (df)
  user_id user_type
0       a  Frequent
1       a  Frequent
2       a  Frequent
3       c    Single
4       b  Frequent
5       b  Frequent
6       t    Single
```

EDIT:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user_id':list('aaacbbt')})
print (df)
  user_id
0       a
1       a
2       a
3       c
4       b
5       b
6       t
```

Here [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) remove all duplicates row by column `user_id` and return only first row (default parameter is `keep='first'`):

```
df_single = df.drop_duplicates('user_id')
print (df_single)
  user_id
0       a
3       c
4       b
6       t
```

But [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) return `True`s for all dupes without first:

```
print (df['user_id'].duplicated())
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
5     True
6    False
Name: user_id, dtype: bool

df_freq = df[df['user_id'].duplicated()]
print (df_freq)
  user_id
1       a
2       a
5       b
```

Comment: So, I checked `df.user_type.value_counts()` against `len(df_single)` and `len(df_freq)` but the values were off. `df_single = df[df.drop_duplicates('user_id')]` and `df_freq = df[df['user_id'].duplicated()]`

Comment: @handavidbang - Yes?

Comment: @handavidbang - I add explanation to your functions, it return something else.

Comment: Thanks! I accepted your answer since you were extremely detailed and circled back to answer my questions.

Answer (score 2):

Using jezrael's data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user_id':list('aaacbbt')})
```

You can use array slicing

```
df.assign(
    user_type=
    np.array(['Single', 'Frequent'])[
        df['user_id'].duplicated(keep=False).astype(int)
    ]
)

  user_id user_type
0       a  Frequent
1       a  Frequent
2       a  Frequent
3       c    Single
4       b  Frequent
5       b  Frequent
6       t    Single
```

Answer (score 2):

Data from Jez , method involve `value_counts`

```
df.user_id.map(df.user_id.value_counts().gt(1).replace({True:'Frequent',False:'Single'}))
Out[52]: 
0    Frequent
1    Frequent
2    Frequent
3      Single
4    Frequent
5    Frequent
6      Single
Name: user_id, dtype: object
```

Comment: Plus1 from me, I would like upvote your solutions more ;)

Comment: @jezrael I always forget the `duplicates`, thank you for your great solution :-)